# Fill() Method becomes slow in .net (ADO)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ado.net, fill

In my .net application am facing a `performance problem`. One of my Stored procedure dealing with more than `two tables having 30,000 records`. But the `SP itself returns fastly`. but in my `DataAccesss` it will take more time for fill that into `DataTable`

My datataccess is

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;//cmd-sqlcommand object
conn.Open();//conn-sqlconnection object
adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();

return dt;
```

If any body know the solution for better performance please share.

Comment: Why you want to *read all* rows at once?

Comment: But am taking only some rows at a time . (between 10 to 100 based on users selection). Now also it geting slow. ma sp contains UNION .

Comment: please refer to http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html, or search SO. I've answered similar questions many times myself, as have others.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : Can u please share the link

Comment: The only link you need I already posted. I think you should be able to search SO yourself....

Comment: The issue sounds related to the SQL within the stored procedure.  Can you please post it here?  Also, when you say slow, how slow? How many seconds does it take to retrieve the 30K recs?  Unions require gathering all recs and culling out duplicates, whereas "union all" returns all records without the culling pass.